# Integral elements over a ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $S$ be a ring, $R\subseteq S$ a subring and $y,s\in S$ s.t $y^2=cy+d, z^2=az+b$ for $a,b,c,d\in R$.
> I need to find $f(x), g(x)\in R[x]$ s.t $g(yz)=f(y+z)=0$.

So I defined the subring $S'=R[y,z]\subseteq S$. Now, generators of $R[y,z]$ are $\{1,y,z,yz\}$ since for every degree bigger than $1$ for $y$ or $z$ can be presented of multiplication of degrees $2$ and $1$, and degree $2$ can be presented as a combination of $1$ and $y$ or $z$.

Now I defined $\mu_{y+z}:S'\rightarrow S$, $R$-modules homomorphism which is basically multiplication by $y+z$. Now I'm looking for the matrix representing this homomorphism.

So by looking at $\mu_{y+z}(1),\mu_{y+z}(y),\mu_{y+z}(z),\mu_{y+z}(yz)$ one can then get that the representing matrix (with respect to $\{1,y,z,yz\}$) is
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
    0&d&b&0\\ 1&c&0&b\\ 1&0&a&d\\0&1&1&a+c\end{pmatrix}$$
and I want to claim that $P_A(y+z)=0$. Is this true? Couldn't find an eigenvalue correspoding to $y+z$ though.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/267930/121097

Comment: @user26857 I think my question here is why can I look at plugging $y+z$ in the characteristic polynomial, the same as plugging $\mu_{y+z}$ or $A$ in the characteristic polynomial

Comment: Right. Let's consider an example: a module $M$ and an endomorphism $\phi$ of $M$ defined by $\phi(x)=ax$. Suppose that $\phi^2+3\phi+2=0$. Then  $(\phi^2+3\phi+2)(x)=0$ for all $x$. We get $a^2x+3ax+2x=0$ for all $x$, that is, $(a^2+3a+2)x=0$ for all $x$. This means that $a^2+3a+2$ annihilates $M$. But your $M$ has a special feature: it contains the unity of $S$!

Comment: @user26857 Why do I care that $M$ contains the unity? That means $a^2+3a+2=0$?

Comment: Isn't this obvious or I missed something? (A module can have non-zero annihilator, but I think this is not the case here.)

Comment: @user26857 No no it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/267930/121097) we learn that $\mu_{y+z}:S'\to S'$ is a "root" of the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Then $P_A(y+z)(s')=0$ for all $s'\in S'$. In particular, $P_A(y+z)(1)=0$ which tells us that $P_A(y+z)=0$.

**Edit.**
$$P_A(t)=b^2-2bd+d^2-abc-bc^2-a^2d-acd+(2ab+2bc+2cd+2ad-a^2c-ac^2)t+(a^2-2b-2d+3ac+c^2)t^2-2(a+c)t^3+t^4$$
and this is consistent with the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If software is available, elimination gives a quick result. Say, eliminate $y$, $z$ from the equalities
$$y^2 - c y - d =0 \\
z^2 - a y - b = 0 \\
t - y - z = 0$$
and [get](http://GroebnerBasis%5B%20%7By%5E2%20-%20c%20y%20-%20d,%20z%5E2%20-%20a%20z%20-%20b,%20t%20-%20(y+z)%7D,%20%7Bt,a,b,c,d%7D,%20%7By,z%7D%5D)
$$b^2 - a b c - b c^2 - a^2 d - 2 b d - a c d + d^2 + 2 a b t - a^2 c t + 2 b c t - a c^2 t + 2 a d t + 2 c d t + a^2 t^2 - 2 b t^2 + 3 a c t^2 + c^2 t^2 - 2 d t^2 - 2 a t^3 - 2 c t^3 + t^4=0$$